# Create View command - Access denied

Tags: mysql, database, create-view

I am trying to create view of a table by making use of the following command `"create view vendor_view.v as select * from vendor;"`. But I get a message as

> ERROR 1142: CREATE VIEW command denied to user 'myuser'@'%' for table 'v'

I tried to GRANT privileges to the user using the command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But again I get the error as

> ERROR 1044: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'%' to database 'mydb'

Could anyone suggest as to how can I grant privileges?

Comment: A Google search for `mysql documentation` should locate the documentation for the version of MySQL you're using. Read them for the proper syntax for `GRANT` and `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: are you trying to grant as the same user that you are granting too?

Comment: @Marshall Tigerus Yes. I used mysql workbench and used this command. CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `vendor_view` AS select * from vendor; It worked.

Comment: If you don't have the permission to create the view, you may not have grant permission either.  I think you can use SHOW GRANTS FOR <username> to see it

Comment: @Marshall Tigerus: It displays in the tables that the username has GRANT ALL permissions.